# mysql select base on primary condition

Tags: mysql

If primary condition matched, return result base on primary condition no matter secondary condition matched or not, if no matched result, then return data base on secondary condition.

Take exchange foreign currency for example, I have a exchange rate table, I need to get exchange rate of us dollar : british pound, if there is no, then get exchange rate of british pound : us dollar. If both have, only return us dollar : british pound.

```
id    origin_currency     target_currency     rate_from     rate_to
1     1                   2                   1             0.75    
2     2                   1                   1             1.34
```

For above data, the query sql should only return first record.

I can use following sql to get what I want:

```
select * from exchange_rate 
where origin_currency = 1 and target_currency = 2 
union 
select * from exchange_rate 
where origin_currency = 2 and target_currency = 1 
limit 1
```

However, is there any other better solution?

Comment: How do you know which record is US Dollar to Pound Sterling and vice-versa?  I guess I'm stuck at seeing why you have forex data where the two conversion rates for a pair are not inverses of each other.  How do you plan to use this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the relevant rows, sort them by `origin_currency = ? DESC` and the limit the number of rows (or just read the first row from your result). See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ea9a/9).

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    currency
WHERE
    (origin_currency = 1 AND target_currency = 2) OR
    (origin_currency = 2 AND target_currency = 1)
ORDER BY
    origin_currency = 1 DESC
LIMIT
    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this fiddle [sql_fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656817/4)

```
SELECT *
FROM currency
WHERE
  (origin_currency, target_currency) =
  (SELECT origin_currency, target_currency FROM currency
   WHERE (origin_currency, target_currency)=(1,2)
           UNION ALL
           SELECT origin_currency, target_currency 
           FROM currency WHERE (origin_currency, target_currency)=(2,1)
           LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Could you tell me that why this is better?

Comment: I think, there are many solutions for this condition. My solution is just my perspective. This  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656817/11) is like the best answer.

Comment: thanks for your opinion, it gives me a different perspective.